# How do I Evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{[0,1]} x\sin(\frac{n}{x})dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Would a viable strategy be to subtitute $y=\frac{n}{x}$ and then use integration by parts? I'm not sure If i'm able to do this, what are the technical difficulties that I need to be aware of?

I'm so poor at Lebesgue integration >.<. I would really appreciate somebody taking the time to wal me through this.. :-(

Comment: You should try this strategy. Lebesgue is not really involved here

Comment: How do I know that this function is Riemann integrable?

Comment: It is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ if we set $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: Integration by parts could totally do this.

Comment: @DanielFischer But why are we allowed to declare $f(0)=0$? Because we can alter this function on a set of measure zero, and then take the Riemann integral?

Comment: Yes, but speaking of sets of measure $0$ is a bit of overkill when we're dealing with a single point.

Comment: But a technically sound argument would involve initially looking at the integral as a Lebesgue integral, altering it at one point, and then saying that this new integral is Riemann integrable? I feel like i'm starting to understand the power of the Lebesgue Integral.

Comment: No, one can view it as a Riemann integral from the start. By defining the integrand at $0$ in whichever way one can view it as a proper Riemann integral, if one leaves the integrand undefined at $0$, as an improper Riemann integral.

Comment: But the function has already been defined, why can we alter it in whatever way we want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original idea works fine.  If you are concerned about the (removable) singularity of the integrand , then simply write

$$\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_\varepsilon^1 x\sin(n/x)\,dx&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_n^{n/\varepsilon} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\left.\left(\frac{-\cos(x)}{x}\right)\right|_{x=n}^{x=n/\varepsilon}-\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_n^{n/\varepsilon}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\cancelto{0}{\left(\frac{\cos(n)}{n}-\frac{\varepsilon\cos(n/\varepsilon)}{n}\right)}-\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_n^{n/\varepsilon}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}\,dx\\\\
&=-\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_n^{n/\varepsilon}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}\,dx\\\\
\end{align}$$

Noting that $\left|\int_n^{n/\varepsilon}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}\,dx\right|\le \frac1n-\frac{\varepsilon}{n}$, we find that the coveted limit of the integral of interest is $0$.  And we are done.